# How a merge 3 database lists to one and show it on a ListView;

Tags: android, sql, listview, merge

I have 3 database lists and I want to merge them as one and show the data to a list view something like this :

```
vathmoss + " " firstnames + " " +lastnames
```

for now I show only firstnames...

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * From " + PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_USERS_TABLE + ";", null);

        ArrayList<String> vathmoss = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> firstnames = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> lastnames = new ArrayList<>();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            vathmoss.add(c.getString(0));
            firstnames.add(c.getString(1));
            lastnames.add(c.getString(2));
        }
        c.close();

        final ListView listUser = (ListView) popup.findViewById(R.id.listview_user);

        if (!vathmoss.isEmpty() && !firstnames.isEmpty() && !lastnames.isEmpty()) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,firstnames);
            listUser.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this :

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * From " + 
PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_USERS_TABLE + ";", null);

    ArrayList<String> vathmoss = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> firstnames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lastnames = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> mergednames = new ArrayList<>();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        vathmoss.add(c.getString(0));
        firstnames.add(c.getString(1));
        lastnames.add(c.getString(2));

        mergednames.add(c.getString(0) + " " + c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2))
    }
    c.close();

    final ListView listUser = (ListView) popup.findViewById(R.id.listview_user);

    if (!vathmoss.isEmpty() && !firstnames.isEmpty() && !lastnames.isEmpty()) {

        //In the below line, pass mergednames instead of firstname as last parameter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mergednames);
        listUser.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```